# Get the current user's order data in WooCommerce for a specific product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display on a page if the logged in user has ordered a specific product.

I can't find a function in WC_Order that would allow me to get this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full code will look something like this

```
if(wc_customer_bought_product('' , get_current_user_id(), PRODUCT ID)){

//the customer has bought specified product

} else {

//the customer has not bought specified product

}
```

Comment: Ah I thought customer email was optional - edited to fix

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the user has already bought a product then you can use the [wc_customer_bought_product](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/wc_customer_bought_product) function to check that ([documentation reference](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_customer_bought_product))

The code will look like this:

```
wc_customer_bought_product('', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id())
```